# How to select values from the previous row based on two columns where the value columns can alternate

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

From the following `game` table of sports matches:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
| id_ | date_time | tournament_id | round_id | p1_id | p2_id | p1_stat | p2_stat |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
|   1 | NULL      |             1 |        4 |     1 |     3 |       2 |       3 |
|   2 | NULL      |             1 |        5 |     1 |     4 |       4 |       6 |
|   3 | NULL      |             1 |        9 |     1 |     5 |       6 |       9 |
|   4 | NULL      |             1 |       10 |     2 |     1 |       8 |      12 |
|   5 | NULL      |             2 |        4 |     1 |     2 |      10 |      15 |
|   6 | NULL      |             2 |        5 |     4 |     1 |      12 |      18 |
+-----+-----------+---------------+----------+-------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I'm trying to get the stats for each player for their previous match. The output should look like this:

```
+-----+--------------+--------------+
| id_ | prev_p1_stat | prev_p2_stat |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
|   1 | NULL         | NULL         |
|   2 | 2            | NULL         |
|   3 | 4            | NULL         |
|   4 | NULL         | 6            |
|   5 | 12           | 8            |
|   6 | 6            | 10           |
+-----+--------------+--------------+
```

However, the `date_time` column is quite often blank and `id_` is not date sequential. The `tournament` table does have a `date_time` column which is always populated:

```
+-----+------------+
| id_ | date_time  |
+-----+------------+
|   1 | 1997-01-01 |
|   2 | 1997-01-06 |
+-----+------------+
```

This means the `tournament` `date_time` can be used in conjunction with `game` `round_id` to determine the previous match.

I've found the following answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/11277108) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344283/11277108) but they both focus on a single table and don't have the added complexity of having to determine whether the `p1_stat` or the `p2_stat` should be selected.

I've got as far as this query:

```
SELECT 
    g.id_ AS game_id,
    CASE
        WHEN g.p1_id = sq_p1.p1_id THEN sq_p1.p1_stat
        ELSE sq_p1.p2_stat
    END AS prev_p1_stat,
    CASE
        WHEN g.p1_id = sq_p2.p1_id THEN sq_p2.p1_stat
        ELSE sq_p2.p2_stat
    END AS prev_p2_stat
FROM
    test.game AS g
        JOIN
    test.tournament AS t ON t.id_ = g.tournament_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        g.id_ AS match_id,
            t.date_time AS tournament_date,
            g.round_id,
            g.p1_id,
            g.p2_id,
            g.p1_stat,
            g.p2_stat
    FROM
        test.game AS g
    JOIN test.tournament AS t ON t.id_ = g.tournament_id) AS sq_p1 ON (sq_p1.p1_id = g.p1_id
        OR sq_p1.p2_id = g.p1_id)
        AND (sq_p1.tournament_date = t.date_time
        AND sq_p1.round_id < g.round_id
        OR sq_p1.tournament_date < t.date_time)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        g.id_ AS match_id,
            t.date_time AS tournament_date,
            g.round_id,
            g.p1_id,
            g.p2_id,
            g.p1_stat,
            g.p2_stat
    FROM
        test.game AS g
    JOIN test.tournament AS t ON t.id_ = g.tournament_id) AS sq_p2 ON (sq_p2.p1_id = g.p1_id
        OR sq_p2.p2_id = g.p1_id)
        AND (sq_p2.tournament_date = t.date_time
        AND sq_p2.round_id < g.round_id
        OR sq_p2.tournament_date < t.date_time)
ORDER BY t.date_time , g.round_id
```

But this isn't even close to what I'm looking for :(

I've created a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4f14fb77206bf3d35ce402cef8b8157a).

One other thing that's perhaps worth mentioning... I intend to use a couple of versions of this query in a union query such that the final result (including all columns for reference) will look like this:

```
+-----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
| id_ | player_num | player_id | opponent_id | player_stat | opponent_stat | player_prev_stat | opponent_prev_stat |
+-----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
|   1 |          1 |         1 |           3 |           2 |             3 | NULL             | NULL               |
|   1 |          2 |         3 |           1 |           3 |             2 | NULL             | NULL               |
|   2 |          1 |         1 |           4 |           4 |             6 | 2                | NULL               |
|   2 |          2 |         4 |           1 |           6 |             4 | NULL             | 2                  |
|   3 |          1 |         1 |           5 |           6 |             9 | 4                | NULL               |
|   3 |          2 |         5 |           1 |           9 |             6 | NULL             | 4                  |
|   4 |          1 |         2 |           1 |           8 |            12 | NULL             | 6                  |
|   4 |          2 |         1 |           2 |          12 |             8 | 6                | NULL               |
|   5 |          1 |         1 |           2 |          10 |            15 | 12               | 8                  |
|   5 |          2 |         2 |           1 |          15 |            10 | 8                | 12                 |
|   6 |          1 |         4 |           1 |          12 |            18 | 6                | 10                 |
|   6 |          2 |         1 |           4 |          18 |            12 | 10               | 6                  |
+-----+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

Perhaps it makes more sense to do a union and then engineer the previous stats?

For some final info, the actual `game` table has about 1.5m rows and the actual `tournament` table has about 30k rows. I'm using MySQL 8.0.26.

Comment: Since you're using MySQL 8.x you should be able to use the `LAG()` window function to pair a row with the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @Barmer for the direction - here's the query I created using `LAG()`:

```
WITH union_matches AS (
    SELECT 
        g.id_ AS match_id,
        t.date_time AS tournament_date,
        g.round_id AS round_id,
        1 AS player_num,
        g.p1_id AS player_id,
        g.p2_id AS opponent_id,
        g.p1_stat AS player_stat,
        g.p2_stat AS opponent_stat
    FROM
        game AS g
            JOIN
        tournament AS t ON t.id_ = g.tournament_id 
    UNION SELECT 
        g.id_ AS match_id,
        t.date_time AS tournament_date,
        g.round_id AS round_id,
        2 AS player_num,
        g.p2_id AS player_id,
        g.p1_id AS opponent_id,
        g.p2_stat AS player_stat,
        g.p1_stat AS opponent_stat
    FROM
        game AS g
            JOIN
        tournament AS t ON t.id_ = g.tournament_id
)
SELECT 
    match_id,
    player_num,
    player_id,
    opponent_id,
    player_stat,
    opponent_stat,
    LAG(player_stat, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY player_id ORDER BY tournament_date, round_id) AS wrong_player_prev_stat,
    LAG(opponent_stat, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY opponent_id ORDER BY tournament_date, round_id) AS wrong_opponent_prev_stat
FROM
    union_matches
ORDER BY
    tournament_date, round_id, player_num
```

And a [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0391c8684cf9af37c3a15446e5cfe6b0) to the dbfiddle.